# Who is Supreme Leader Snoke?

Tags: character, star-wars, the-force-awakens

Supreme Leader Snoke is, as his title suggests, the supreme commander of the First Order in *Star Wars: The Force Awakens*. His appearance suggests he is large in scale and old (though those are deductions made from his appearance and little else). Further, he is master of Kylo Ren, and is, according the Han, the one responsible for seducing Kylo Ren to the Dark Side.

Who is he?

Comment: Short answer, we do not know yet. I do not think that he is large, only his projection was made large. I think he is an old sith lord.

Comment: Agreed he isn't actually large, his hologram was large. The emperor was shown in a similar manner in TOS.

Comment: We do now, Snoke is one of many clones Emperor Papaltine produced.

Answer (score 5):

**We don't know.**

There is nothing in the movie, nor the wiki's or official Star Wars page to suggest exactly who he is as of yet.

There are many speculations that he could be Darth Plagueis, but ultimately for the time being there is no evidence to back up these claims.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [new interview with Andy Serkis](http://www.ew.com/article/2016/01/02/star-wars-force-awakens-maz-kanata-supreme-leader-snoke-exclusive) who played Snoke on *Entertainment weekly*  in which he says that Snoke is a new addition and not based on another character:

> “When we first started working on it, he had some rough notions of how Snoke was gonna look, but it really hadn’t been fully-formed and it almost came out of discussion and performance,” Serkis added.
>
> Although there was much speculation about who Snoke might turn out to be (one popular theory was that he’d turn out to be a Sith Lord known from the prequels as Darth Plagueis) **he actually turns out to be … just Snoke**.
>
> Serkis said the character was aware of the events from the earlier films but was **a new addition to the storyline**.

Source: http://www.ew.com/article/2016/01/02/star-wars-force-awakens-maz-kanata-supreme-leader-snoke-exclusive

Comment: Perhaps a modified force ghost of Darth Sidious, being him who told that technique to Anakin. Muahahahahahaha. Neeeh just specu-ranting.

Comment: I'd take what the cast and crew say with a grain of salt. J. J. Abrams has made bold-faced lies many times before, like with denying who John Harrison really is, all for the purpose of saving the big reveal.